# Group by not working with 2 fields sum

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

## Table 1: store

```
Id  qty  department
1   20   1
2   10   1
3   05   2
```

## Table 2: store_sub

```
Id   parent_id  sub_qty
1    1          5
2    1          6
3    3          9
```

I want to generate rows to fit this format:

```
Id  department  qty  sub_qty
1   1           30   11
2   2           05   09
```

I currently have the following SQL query:

```
Select store.id,
  store.department,
  sum(store.qty),
  sum(sub_qty)
from store
  left join store_sub on store_sub.parent_id = store.id
  Group by department
```

However, it is not working.

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: What does *your* query output?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: Not errors but the calculation not arrive proper of qty field.

Comment: What output do you see, then?

Comment: 1 @ 1 @ 50 @ 11 and 3 @ 2 @ 5 @ 9.. This @ used for sepherate column. Instead of 30 its displays 50

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `store` with id 1 has two corresponding records in `store_sub` table, which means that `qty` field will appear twice for store 1. You need to sum the 2 tables separately in subqueries and join the summed versions together:

```
select t1.department, t1.sqty, t2.ssubqty
from
  (select department, sum(qty) as sqty from store group by department) t1
left join
  (select s2.department, s1.sum(sub_qty) as ssubqty
   from store_sub s1
   inner join store s2 on s1.parent_id=s2.id
   group by s2.department) t2 on t1.department=t2.department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select store.id, store.department, sum(qty),
sum((select sum(sub_qty) from store_sub where parent_id = store.id group by parent_id )) as sub_qty
from store Group by department
```